# How can i correctly update a table if i used looping statement on a select tag?

Tags: php, loops, select

I'd like to know if how can i manipulate the "`where`" statement in sql code if i used a looping statement in my select tag.

Here's the code i had written.

These one is the code for my "`<select>`"

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * from inventory");
$ctr=0;
while($inventory=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$print=$inventory['item_name'];
$cquantity=$inventory['quantity'];
$selected=array();
?>


<option> <?php echo $print; $selected[$ctr]=$print==$print ? $print : '';?></option>

<?php $ctr++;}
```

And these one is for my SQL code:

```
$sql="Update inventory set quantity='*some quantity here*' where item_name='$selected[$ctr]'";
```

Now, i know that my code will just update the last value of my item_name. I want to know if how can I manipulate my "where" statement which will update the quantity of the selected field in my "`<select>`"

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use Javascript to interpret the selection and then pass it through a POST submission or through an AJAX submission.

The Javascript could be:

```
var quantity = document.getElementById("quantityselect").value
```

This will create a Javascript variable, **quantity**, that is equal to the selected value.  You would then need to create a PHP script that will handle the submission, and then Javascript could submit the form using

```
*formname*.submit
```

Comment: but what will my sql code look like?

It will still update those values which will satisfy the where statement.

Comment: PHP would then create the SQL script based on the submission data.  So, PHP would grab the quantity as $quantity = $_POST["quantityselect"];  and then the SQL would be something like "UPDATE inventory SET quantity = \"$quantity\" WHERE item_name = \"$itemname\"";

Comment: Oops sorry, I think my informations are insufficient.

For clarification, I am making page, a manage-materials page, where all the itemnames are in a drop down list. Then there's an inpt box where you can add or subtract the quantity of that particular item.

I dont have problems of fetching the quantity, instead I am troubled with the itemname because as I said, I used loop in my select tag, which means all the itemnames in my table will appear in the drop down list . Then if i add another item, it will be also added to the drop down list but will be saved to the last looped item name.